# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'TfliteReactNative.loadModel') IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use the tflite-react-native library and have it working on Android but cannot get it to work on iOS.

I have my model and label files in /ios/[app_name]/models/

```
import Tflite from 'tflite-react-native';

let tflite = new Tflite();
var modelFile = 'models/model.tflite';
var labelsFile = 'models/labels.txt';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recognitions: null,
      source: null,
    };
    tflite.loadModel({model: modelFile, labels: labelsFile}, (err, res) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(res);
    });
  }
 ...
}
```

But I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'TfliteReactNative.loadModel')
```

The exact same code works when I run-android so I think it has to do with the location of the model files on the iOS file structure.

I have run pod install / update in the iOS dir etc.

My software versions are:

- macOS - 11.5.2
- xcode - 12.5
- react-native - 0.65.1
- tflite-react-native - 0.0.5

pods:

- TensorFlowLite (1.12.0)
- TfliteReactNative (0.0.4)

Any help is appreciated.